# Finding the biggest nondecreasing Subset in a list using Brute Force approach?

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, brute-force

We have a number list which is *(5, 12, 4, 6, 7, 12, 5, 55, 13, 14)* and I have to find the biggest nondecreasing subset which is **(4, 6, 7, 12)** .

Also it should be solved by brute force approach. I tried to solve it but I am not sure that it is a brute force solution. Any tips would be helpful! (Pseudocode, java code or any help...)

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[] nonDecrease = { 5, 12, 4, 6, 7, 12, 5, 55, 13, 14 };
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();
            list.add(nonDecrease[0]);

            int counter = 0;
            int a = 0;

             for (int i = 1; i < nonDecrease.length; i++) {
                if (nonDecrease[i - 1] < nonDecrease[i]) {
                    list.add(nonDecrease[i]);
                    counter = list.size();
                } else if (nonDecrease[i - 1] > nonDecrease[i] && counter >= a) {
                    a = list.size();

                    if (list.size() >= temp.size() && counter >= a) {
                        temp = list;
                        System.out.println(temp + "t");
                    }
                    list.clear();
                    list.add(nonDecrease[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So, by "subset" you mean "unbroken subsequence"? (Subset could be understood as "any elements, and in any order".)

Comment: yes I mean unbroken subsequence. @tobias_k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bruteforce, you can try this approach. Note that you have `maxLength = maxList.size()` so you don't have to store the extra `maxLength` variable.

```
List<Integer> maxList = new ArrayList(); 

for (int i = 0; i < nonDecrease.length - 1;) {
   int prev = nonDecrease[i];
   List<Integer> currentMaxList = new ArrayList();
   currentMaxList.add(prev);

   int j = i + 1;
   for (; j < nonDecrease.length; j++) {
      if (nonDecrease[j] >= prev) {
          prev = nonDecrease[j];
          currentMaxList.add(prev);
      } else {
          break;
      }
   }
   if (currentMaxList.size() > maxList.size()) {
      // Found new longer
      maxList = currentMaxList;
   }
   // The non-decreasing break at `j` so we continue the next search at j:
   i = j;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however there is an error at i=j part it gives an undeclared j variable error because it is outside the second for loop and also it goes to infinity inside the second for insert    System.out.println("INSIDE"); under the   if (nonDecrease[j] >= prev) { and you will see.